# Advanced List Coding using multiple lists

Tags: python

So we are given two lists.

```
groups = [[0,1],[2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]

A = [[[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[2]], [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]
```

How do we replace the the elements in `A` with their corresponding indexes in groups: i.e., replace the `0` and `1` in `A` with `0`, the `2` in `A` with `1`, the `3`, `4` and `5` with `2` and so on.

Output:

```
A = [[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[1]], [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far, what are you struggling with, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a dictionry which store the index value for those numbers and then for those number in list A add the index

```
groups = [[0,1],[2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]

A = [[[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[2]], [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]

from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(int)

for i in range(len(groups)):
    for j in groups[i]:
        dic[j]=i

for i in A:
    for j in i:
        for l in range(len(j)):
            j[l] = dic[j[l]]
```

output

```
[[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]],
 [[1]],
 [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]],
 [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
  [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
  [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
  [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no attempt from your side, here you go :

```
def f(l,i):
    for k in l:
        if i in k:
            return l.index(k)

output_ = [[[f(groups,n) for n in a0] for a0 in a] for a in A]
```

**Output** :

```
[[[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[1]], [[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]], [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def replace_items(i, inner_list, *lists):
    for l in lists:
        for item in l:
            if item in inner_list:
                index= l.index(item)
                l[index] = i

for i,inner_list in enumerate(groups):
    for lists in A:
        replace_items(i, inner_list, *lists)

print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your groups into a dictionary, it will be easy to process the 3 level list using a list comprehension:

```
groupDict = { v:i for i,g in enumerate(groups) for v in g }
A = [ [ [ groupDict[z] for z in yz ] for yz in xyz] for xyz in A ]
```